# How do I navigate to a different route on a button click in Kendo MVVM

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, routes

I want to navigate to a route when the user clicks a 'next' button, using Kendo MVVM, to display a view. The route will display the next page of a single page application using:

```
myRouter.route("/AppDetails", function () {
    layoutView.showIn("#content", appDetailsView);
}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/spa/router#navigation. This code:

```
myRouter.navigate("/AppDetails");
```

should do this. Isn't it working?